# Tizen wear: 401 response error when fetching data from Nest API

Tags: jquery, tizen, nest-api, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm currently developing quite simple app using NEST API:

- Tizen 2.3.1 SDK,
- web based (JS, HTML, CSS) application,
- wearable devices are the target,
- standalone app
- powered by Samsung Galaxy Gear S2 watch

**The problem:**
I'm getting 401 error when I'm trying to get data from NEST API.

First I'm getting token and it works perfectly fine:

```
function authNest() {
$.ajax({
    url: authUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.access_token);
        getNest(data.access_token);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

That means I'm properly paired with mobile phone, internet connection works and I have proper privileges.
Token works for sure. I've checked it with Postman, curl command and with REST client app for Android (3 different solutions works fine).

After getting a token I'm making REST API call with that token, and it looks like that:

```
function get(token) {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://developer-api.nest.com",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    },
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

But then I'm getting an error response. I also tried request using only XMLHttpRequest (without ajax/jquery) - I'm getting the same error response.

Error:

> {      "readyState":4,
>   "responseText":"{\"error\":\"unauthorized\",\"type\":\"https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/error-messages#auth-error\",\"message\":\"unauthorized\",\"instance\":\"bfd045c0-e7ff-4a75-bbba-e6199be03c4a\"}",
>   "status":401,    "statusText":"Unauthorized" }

So I'm getting server response at least. But I'm not authorize and I'm completely don't have idea WTF.

Are there some problems with oAuth2.0 on Tizen wear?
Why the server don't want to accept my requests even though it returned token before?
Maybe some hidden constrains?

Of course I've defined features and privileges in config.xml: internet, network.internet, network.wifi, download, location and so on.

Pls help :)

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of debbuging and searching I've found an answer.
First, Tizen browser is sending request with proper headers and token.
Then it got 307 HTTP code - with asking to redirect - of course. 
It's not visible without debugging in external tools like Chrome Developers Tools (console+network tab). Tizen Studio/sdb dlog shows nothing!
In the background Tizen redirects properly - but almost properly! 
Second request to endpoint does not contain headers and token so it cannot be authorized on the server. That's why I got 401 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

add

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Hi. thx for quick response. I've already tried adding headers in different form. It's not working.

Comment: aren't you passing something to the api?

Comment: Hi. I'm passing basic info like token and headers but the major goal is to GET json from API. :)

Comment: debug you ajax in the console see if the headers are properly send tot the api

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
url: "https://developer-api.nest.com?auth="+token
```